# Как вывести часть li-элементов, а остальные спрятать под кнопкой "next"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, tabs

Сделал обычные табы в Bootstrap. В каждом табе должно быть по несколько `<select>` с несколькими `<option>`. Если количество селектов превышает 5, хотелось бы вывести в табе только первые пять и добавить кнопку "Next" для перехода к следующим. При нажатии на кнопку, селекты будут плавно уезжать в левую сторону и исчезать, а с правой стороны так же плавно появляться следующие селекты. Может кто-нибудь знает как написать универсальный код, который бы в зависимости от количества селектов в каждом табе добавлял или не добавлял кнопки "Next" и "Previous"?
http://jsfiddle.net/crudetone/y6ybzjo0/